# Creating tkinter gui.How to display information when ID number provided

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on creating a gui and could use some help. There are three programs that build off of each other. MY imput will be two CSV files, Examples below:

items4.csv
12345,Italy,100
13579,China,50
ETC.

transactions4.csv
12345,15
13579,10
12345,20
13579,-10

What I want it to do is upon running the gui will open and the window will ask for the "Item ID" Upon entering an id, say 12345, it will open up a new window that displays the following:  getID, getName, getAvailableStart, and getAvailableEnd, all of these definitions are were created by the travelclass program (found below) when the program travelToolbox reads the two CSV files.

Note:  Both the travelClass and travelToolbox programs are working fine. IT is only travelSystem that needs changing at this point

What I've done:
At this point I have managed to get the travelSystems presents the initial GUI however it doesn't matter what I enter in the entry box because when I hit the open button the next gui opens up but it only shows the information found in the first line of items4.csv. I think my main issue is line 34 or may be line 16.  Let me know if any other information is needed.

I could really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

- travelsystem

  ```
  from travelToolbox import readItems, readTransactions  
  from tkinter import *  
  from tkinter import font  
  import tkinter as tk  

  class myApp :  
      def __init__(self, top, itemRecords) :  
         self.root = top  
         # Create a container Frame at the bottom  
         self.bframe = Frame(self.root)  
         self.bframe.pack(side=BOTTOM) # Create Label  
         self.xlabel = Label(self.root, text="Item ID")  
         self.xlabel.pack(side=LEFT)  
         self.xentry = Entry(self.root, bd=5)  # Create Entry box  
         self.xentry.pack(side=LEFT)  
         self.xentry.focus_set()  # Set focus in Entry box  
         self.xopen = Button(self.root, text="Open",   command=self.showStockItem) # Create open Button  
         self.xopen.pack(side=LEFT)  
         self.xquit = Button(self.bframe, text="Quit", command=self.quitit )   # Create quit Button  
         #self.root instead of bframe  
         self.xquit.pack(side=BOTTOM)  

  def showStockItem(self):  
      tbl = Toplevel()  # Create Toplevel window  
      hdr = font.Font(underline=1, weight="bold")  # Create header font  
      tid = Label(tbl, text="ID", font=hdr)  # Create 4 column headers in grid  
      tid.grid(row=0, column=0)  
      tlast = Label(tbl, text="Name", font=hdr)  
      tlast.grid(row=1, column=0)  
      tfirst = Label(tbl, text="Start", font=hdr)  
      tfirst.grid(row=2, column=0)  
      tlabel = Label(tbl, text="End", font=hdr)  
      tlabel.grid(row=3, column=0)  
      for rec in itemRecords.values() :  
          tid = Label(tbl, text= rec.getID())  # Create 4 column headers in grid  
          tid.grid(row=0, column=1)  
          tlast = Label(tbl, text= rec.getName())  
          tlast.grid(row=1, column=1)  
          tfirst = Label(tbl, text= rec.getAvailableStart())  
          tfirst.grid(row=2, column=1)  

          tlabel = Label(tbl, text= rec.getAvailableEnd())  
          tlabel.grid(row=3, column=1)  
  #self.xquit.pack(side=BOTTOM) #May not need this.    
       return

  def quitit(self):  
     self.root.destroy()
     return


  itemsFileName = "items4.csv"
  transactionsFileName = "transactions4.csv"

  # itemRecords is a dictionary of stockItem records indexed by item ID
  itemRecords = {}

  # Read the items from itemsFileName into itemRecords
  readItems(itemsFileName, itemRecords)

  # Read the transactions from transactionsFileName into itemRecords
  readTransactions(transactionsFileName, itemRecords)

  top = tk.Tk()
  #top = Travel()
  app = myApp(top, itemRecords)
  top.mainloop()
  ```

**Other files:**

- travelToolbox

  ```
   import csv
   from travelClass import travelItem

   def readItems(itemsFileName, itemRecords) :
   # readItems reads items from itemsFileName into the itemRecords dictionary

   # Open itemsFileName and create a CSV file reader
   itemsFile = open(itemsFileName, 'r')
   itemsReader = csv.reader(itemsFile)

   # Process each row of the items file
   for row in itemsReader :
       # Get the values for the record
  (iid, iname, icount) = row
  iid = str(iid)
  iname = str(iname)
  icount = int(icount)

  # Check if this ID is not yet in itemRecords
  if (not(iid in itemRecords)) :
      # Create a travelItem object and add it to itemRecords
      itemRecord = travelItem(iid, iname, icount)
      itemRecords[iid] = itemRecord

  def readTransactions(transactionsFileName, itemRecords) :
  # readTransactions reads transactions from transactionsFileName into the itemRecords dictionary
  transactionFile = open(transactionsFileName, 'r')
  transactionReader = csv.reader(transactionFile)
  for row in transactionReader :
      # Get the values for the record
      (iid, itransaction) = row
      iid = str(iid)
      itransaction = int(itransaction)
      itemRecords[iid].appendTransaction(itransaction)
      #for key, value in itemRecords.items() :

      transactionFile.close()
  ```
- travelClass

class travelItem :

```
 Class travelItem :
 def __init__(self, itemID, itemName, itemCount) :
    # Constructor to create inventoryItem CORRECT
    self.id = itemID
    self.name = itemName
    self.AvailableStart = itemCount
    self.transactions = []

def getID(self) :
    # getID returns the tour ID CORRECT
      return(self.id)

def getName(self) :
    # getName returns the tour name CORRECT
     return (self.name)

def setName(self, newName) : 
    # setName sets the tour name
    self.name = newName

def getAvailableStart(self) :
    # returns the starting availability
    return (self.AvailableStart)

def appendTransaction(self, num) :
    # appendTransaction appends a transaction to the transactions list
    self.transactions.append(num)

def getTransactions(self) :
    # getTransactions returns the list of transactions
    return (self.transactions)

def getReservations(self) :
    # returns the total of reservation transactions
    total = 0
    for num in self.transactions :
        if ((num) > 0):
            total += (num)
    self.Reservations = total
    return(self.Reservations)

def getCancellations(self) :
    # returns the total of cancellation transactions
    total = 0
    for num in self.transactions :
        if (num <= 0): 
            total += (num)
    return(total)

def getAvailableEnd(self) :
    # returns the ending availability, which is availableStart minus transactions
    self.AvailableEnd = ((self.AvailableStart) - (self.Reservations) - (self.getCancellations()))
    return(self.AvailableEnd)
```

Comment: Please tead [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You also need to fix your error ndentatipn.

Comment: My bad about the indentation. It got a little mixed up when I was formatting this.